# How to add galleries to nodes in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, gallery, nodes

I have site with news, and I want to make it possible for admin to add image gallery to articles (nodes) he wants. So, the idea is to make gallery image field for every content type from which images should be taken, and if admin wants gallery for that article he can upload images, if he don't he can just leave it alone, and Drupal renders that node without gallery perfectly normal.

So, I made that gallery image field for every content type, and used Views module for taking and rendering pictures. But, whereas Views taking pictures at content type level, not node level, that is the reason why unpleasant consequence appear: gallery from particular node, shows on every node of that type.

My question is how to make galleries relative to particular nodes (specific gallery for specific node). And it should be extremely easy for admin to manipulate.

Comment: I think you should ask on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ too...

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few modules you could use for this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery or
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

Since you've already created the field, you could probably use Field Slideshow and it will turn your image field into a slideshow on the display for the node.